# Jquery Mobile Pre-Load Page

Tags: json, api, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with jquery mobile, when I load a page, it pulls the data from an exposed API in JSon format, parses it, then inserts the data into the DOM to display the page, but what's happening is the page shows, then 2-4 seconds passes while it's parsing the data, then inserts the data on to the page, and it is not very visually pleasing at all, just wondering how I can pre-load the DOM and parse the JSON before the pageChange animation fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to handle dynamically generated pages in JQuery Mobile is to bind the page retrieval to the beforepagechange event of your document. Once the page is retreived, you can proceed with the proper changepage.

For instance, with a getPageFromAPI function retrieving the complete Jquery object for your page accessed with the URL "newPageURL"

```
$(document).bind( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
    if ( (typeof data.toPage === "string") && (data.toPage == "newPageURL")  ) {
        e.preventDefault();    //to make sure we prevent standard page change
        getPageFromAPI({success: function (newPage) {
                $.mobile.changePage(newPage)
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm, I'm doing that, im following the example in the jquery mobile documentation, but for some reason the $.getJSON isn't being fired and it's not pulling anything from the API

Comment: I got this working sort of, it doesnt work on the first time the page triggers, for some reason it's not loading into the DOM, I even tried $.mobile.loadPage("desired_page.html"); and the beginning of my getPageFromAPI function, however, it loads the page, then loads the JSON into the page, I want it to show a loading wheel sort of, until the entire function is complete so the user doesnt see a blank page fill up.